# Alias to prompt for tab completion for a set of directories?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias, autocomplete

Is it possible to make a bash alias, which would be able to prompt me for tab-completion of a set of directories?

let's say I have a number of source code controlled projects, main path of each located under `~/projs/<projname>/trunk`

Now, I have created a Bash alias, which allows more convenient switching:

```
go-to <projname>
```

will attempt to `cd ~/projs/<projname>/trunk` regardless of where I am in file system.

Is it possible to somehow get tab completion prompt for `<projname>` as I write `go-to[space][Tab]` so I could see which projnames I have available?

(This is recent Ubuntu distro)

Answer (score 2):

It is not alias job to do this, it is called *programmable completion* ([see man bash for details](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html)). The minimal completion example for `bash` looks like this:

```
_go-to()  {
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "~/projs/proj1/trunk ~/projs/proj2/trunk" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") );
}
complete -F _go-to go-to
```

So first we created a function `_go-to` and then bind it to command named `go-to`.

Now `go-to <tab>` will get completed to `go-to /home/user/projs/proj` and another `<tab>` will list propositions:

```
/home/user/projs/proj1/trunk /home/user/projs/proj2/trunk
```

Comment: I think the proposed completions should be something like the output of `find $HOME/projs -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;`, or maybe even check that a subdirectory `trunk` exists.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that I could do it easier by: 
``complete -W "$(ls -1 ~/projs/)" go-to``

Comment: @Gnudiff If all your projects are in the same directory, then yes, although I would not use `ls` for this unless you are sure there are no whitespaces in their names. You can also first build a variable with their names under special conditions (like e.g. recently modified directory) and only then `complete -W "$var" ...`. Above is only the minimal example to grasp an idea.